Is there a way to use a function to generate a union type?
I'm building a telegram bot with TypeScript and GrammyJs. I have some commands that I will be using many times and I also need to use the names of these commands inside my code as a union type. How can I create a function that can generate that union type?
The code goes a little like this:
import commands from "./commands.js" // returns Array<command>

let commandStrings = commands.map(command => command.name) // returns Array<string>

type SaveCommandProps = {
 executedBy:string; 
 commandName: // i want to dynamicaly generate an union type  
}

function someRandomThing({executedBy:'lana', CommandName:"generated Value from import commands"}:SaveCommandProps){}



You cannot. Either make that a typescript file, and add as const to its export so that you get a type containing the strings, or add a build step that generates the code of the union type before compiling your TypeScript.

yeah when i posted the post it hit me. That even if if it is possible i still wont be able to use it in Dev cz it needs to be treated first.
just out of curiosity is there anyway to have functions like that in typescript ?

how would you go about do it ?
to make it available during dev and like  constantly updated if anything changes and somewhat dynamic ?

It is likely impossible without writing your own dev step, but the specifics depend strongly on having a usable example. What does this js file look like and what type is command? Right now this isn't a [mre] because I can't use it to reproduce the issue easily. Do you have a link to a web IDE project that shows it happening?

Not sure what you mean by "even if if it is possible i still wont be able to use it in Dev cz it needs to be treated first." To have a file that is getting dynamically updated during development, you choose your favourite build tool that includes a watch mode and write a plugin for it. Details would depend on which build chain you are using, the question is far too broad to be answered on StackOverflow generically.
